# How to remove stop words from dataframe, pyspark or sql?

Tags: sql, dataframe, pyspark, stop-words

So for instance I have this dataframe.

```
data = Seq(("Novelist Sparks turns screenwriter with this film, which combines his usual themes (beaches, grieving teens, cancer) as a vehicle for Cyrus to put her childhood career behind her. It's exactly what we expect, but it's also fairly watchable."))
df = data.toDF("sentence")
```

What I want to do is remove all stop words from this row or column value and count the words after removing stop words.

pyspark or sql code example, both are good.

Answer (score 1):

We made the [Fugue project](https://github.com/fugue-project/fugue/) to port native Python or Pandas code to Spark or Dask. This lets you can keep the logic very readable by expressing it in native Python. Fugue can then port it to Spark for you with one function call.

First we start with a test Pandas DataFrame:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"id": [1,2,3], "sentences": ["this is sentence one.", "this is sentence two.", "this is sentence three"]})
```

Then we create a pandas-based function to handle stopwords

```py
def process(df:pd.DataFrame) -> pd.DataFrame:
    from nltk.corpus import stopwords
    from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
    stop = set(stopwords.words('english'))
    df['processed_sentences'] = df['sentences'].apply(lambda x: ' '.join([word for word in x.split() if word not in (stop)])
    return df
```

If you want to count the words, just add it as another column. Now we can bring this function to Fugue and test it.

```py
from fugue import transform
transform(df, process, schema="*, processed_sentences:str")
```

Now that we see it works, we can use it on Spark by specifying the engine

```py
import fugue_spark
transform(df, process, schema="*, processed_sentences:str", engine="spark").show()
```

Note `.show()` is needed because of Spark's lazy evaluation.
The output is:

```
+---+--------------------+-------------------+
| id|           sentences|processed_sentences|
+---+--------------------+-------------------+
|  1|this is sentence ...|      sentence one.|
|  2|this is sentence ...|      sentence two.|
|  3|this is sentence ...|     sentence three|
+---+--------------------+-------------------+
```

The Fugue transform function can take in a Pandas DataFrame or Spark DataFrame, and it will output a Spark DataFrame if you are using the Spark engine.

I think you have to import the `nltk.corpus` inside the function so that it is executed on the workers rather than the driver. You need nltk installed on the workers because they need access to `stopwords.words`.